# How do you re-stroke a path to another color with exact same result?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm developing an app which involves drawing lines. Every times the user moves the finger, that point is added to an path and also added to the CGContext as the example below.

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(cacheContext, point1.x, point1.y);
CGContextAddCurveToPoint(cacheContext, ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y, ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y, point2.x, point2.y);
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, point1.x, point1.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, NULL, ctrl1_x, ctrl1_y, ctrl2_x, ctrl2_y, point2.x, point2.y);
```

Now when I want to add it and stroke it in black I use the following code

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor([UIColor blackcolor].CGColor)
CGContextAddPath(cacheContext,path);
CGContextStrokePath(cacheContext);
```

However the line that gets stroked this time will be a bit smaller then the one that was drawn before. This will result in a slight border around the stroked path. So my question is: How can I get the stroked path to be identical to the path that was drawn into the CGcontext?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to anti-aliasing. The path is a geometric ideal. The bitmap generated by stroking the path with a given width, color, etc. is imperfect. The ideal shape covers some pixels completely, but only covers others partially.

The result without anti-aliasing (and assuming an opaque color) is to fully paint pixels which mostly lie within the ideal shape and don't touch the pixels which mostly lie outside of it. That leaves visible jaggies on anything other than vertical or horizontal lines. If you later draw the same path with the same stroke parameters again, exactly the same pixels will be affected and, since they are being fully painted, you can completely replace the old drawing with the new.

With anti-aliasing, any pixel which is only partially within the ideal shape is not completely painted with the new color. Rather, the stroke color is applied in proportion to the percentage of the pixel which is within the ideal shape. The color that was already in that pixel is retained in inverse proportion. For example, a pixel which is 43% within the ideal shape will get a color which is 43% of the stroke color plus 57% of the prior color.

That means that stroking the path a second time with a different color will not completely replace the color from a previous stroke. If you fill a bitmap with white and then stroke a path in red, some of the pixels along the edge will mix a little red with a little of the white to give light red or pink. If you then stroke that path in blue, the pixels along the edge will mix a little blue with a little of the color that was there, which is a light red or pink. That will give a magenta-ish color.

You can disable anti-aliasing using `CGContextSetShouldAntialias()`, but then you risk getting jaggies. You would have to do this around both strokings of the path.

Alternatively, you can clear the context to some background color before redrawing the path. But for that, you need to be able to completely redraw everything you want to appear.